# Using progress bar in cli

Tags: go, command-line, progress-bar

I have code which execute npm install as below:

```
cmd := exec.Command("npm", "install")
```

and it finish with

```
if err = cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
    logs.("Error running %s: %v\n", cp[1:], err)
    return err
}
```

I want to use progress bar and I've found the following
https://github.com/cheggaaa/pb
but since I dont control the time of the execution ( I dont know when it finish), how can I use it ?

**UPDATE**

Since we cannot calculate the time that will take (it depends on network etc) so I just want to show that something is working, 
**show that the process is running** ,since the user wait 20 sec and he think that nothing working, how it can be done?

Comment: What do you mean by 'I dont know when it finish' ? The code you showed does this

Comment: @old_mountain - I want that meanwhile the progress bar will work and and after wait it will finish...

Comment: @old_mountain - meanwhile (during the npm install which takes some time and user doesnt see anything until someting is printed to the cli...)

Comment: How would you show a user progress information that you don't have?

Comment: @Adrian- I want to show to user something , since it taks about 20 sec until he see something , so its not classic progress bar but it show something that the process is running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very short answer is: you can't if you don't have any indicative units.

The slightly longer answer: Providing feedback to the user can be done in several ways. If you don't have granular progress information (E.g.: n out of 10 steps has been completed or n out of 10 seconds have passed), you can't really show a *meaningful* progress bar.

You can provide the user with feedback about what's happening. This is, however, something npm already does so why not just show that output instead?

If you only care about showing a progress bar regardless of how meaningful it might be, what you could do is guesstimate how much time the process is going to take. Simply time it once and use that as a point of reference.

Comment: Downside of guesstimating: you end up with Windows-quality progress bars, where they are _basically_ completely and totally useless except as a placebo.

Comment: is there a way to show just a progress, not the real steps that was finish like. just to show something (that we are working )

Comment: @shopiaT Sure, but that's typically called a "spinner" or the infamous "hour glass" you might know from Windows. On terminals you sometimes have a rotating dash. Perhaps you can find some inspiration here: https://github.com/sindresorhus/cli-spinners